# i am trying to plot 35 graphs in matplotlib but output is very small

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

As I mentioned in the title that I am trying to plot 35 graphs using subplot as single output but I am getting a small output. I have tried tight_layout also but nothing is happening. What to do?[image: THE Output I am getting]

Comment: look into the matplotlib doc, you have also provided no code for us to work from

Answer (score 0):

have you tried increasing the `figsize` in `plt.subplots(nrows = 18, ncols = 2, figsize = (30,20))` (or some other values, just try for yourself).

Otherwise, would it be an option to change it to a 7x5 layout?

Comment: I have provided fig size earlier in code as 15 10 not working

Comment: It is difficult to solve this problem without any access to the code. Could you show the general outline?

Comment: Furthermore, would a 7x5 layout be an option?? The plots probably  would not be as flat compared to the current situation.